# Bootstrap custom dropdown with animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone have idea how to make bootstrap dropdown look like this?

My problem is to customize the basic dropdown menu to make disappear borders, and make the bottom blue line slowly move down while opening.

http://prntscr.com/g3u587

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756773/8317974

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Make Dropdown arrow(caret icon bootstrap) change On Click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755447/how-to-make-dropdown-arrowcaret-icon-bootstrap-change-on-click)

Comment: Sorry, did not find. Thanks. But for me important whit the bottom line which is not defined in these answers

Comment: @slacker before commenting at least read the description carefully.

Comment: ok sir sorry. and thank you.

Comment: @davodor check the fiddle in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Something Like this with CSS

CSS

```
.dropdown-toggle{
  border:none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline:0;
}
.dropdown-toggle:active{
  box-shadow:none;
}

.btn.dropdown-toggle:focus{
  outline:0;
}

.dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] .caret{
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  transition:all ease 0.5s;
}
.dropdown-toggle .caret{
  transition:all ease 0.5s;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu{
  height:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0;
  display:block;
  border:none;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(33,150,243,0.2);
  border-bottom:1px solid #2196F3;
  transition:all ease 0.5s;
  border-radius:0px;
  padding-left:2px;
  padding-right:2px;
}
.dropdown.open > .dropdown-menu{
  height:auto;

}
.dropdown.open > .dropdown-menu > li a:hover{
  background-color: #2196F3;
  border-radius:5px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/vbrLsbu5/8/)

Style Accordingly.

Hope this Helps..

Comment: great... CSS trick works too.